# Linux keyboard switch parentheses and square brackets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-layout

How do you switch the parenthesis and square bracket keys in Linux? Specifically Ubuntu x64 in a virtual box running under Windows 7, using an otherwise standard US keyboard layout - I already have them switched in Windows, but Linux ignores this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keymaps](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_keymaps.htm)
is what you are looking for.

> COMPLETE KEYCODE DEFINITIONS
>
> Each complete key definition line is of the form: keycode keynumber =
>   keysym keysym keysym... keynumber is the internal identification
>   number of the key, roughly equivalent to the scan code of it.
>   keynumber can be given in decimal, octal or hexadecimal notation.
>   Octal is denoted by a leading zero and hexadecimal by the prefix 0x.

Also use `dumpkeys -l` to view current configuration

example:

```
plain keycode 14 = BackSpace
control alt keycode 83 = Boot
alt keycode 105 = Decr_Console
alt keycode 106 = Incr_Console
```